# Vue computed inline styles with dynamic variables not working in Safari/IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, vue.js, safari

I have dynamic styles on element from computed variable styles. In computed property styles I return css with variables. In other browsers it's working just fine but in Safari or IE the inline style

Element:

```
<button :style="styles" name="button"></button>
```

Computed variable styles:

```
styles() {
 return {
      border: `${this.is('flat')?0:1}px solid ${_color.getColor(this.color,1)}`,
      background: this.hoverx?_color.getColor(this.color,.1):'transparent',
      color:_color.getColor(this.textColor,1) || _color.getColor(this.color,1)
 }
}
```

Here is how it looks like in browsers

#### Inline css of element in Chrome:

[image: Inline css of element in Chrome]

#### Inline css of element in Safari

[image: Inline css of element in Safari]

I found out that when I predefine css property, everything is working

```
styles() {
 return {
      border: `${this.is('flat')?0:1}px solid red`,
      background: this.hoverx?_color.getColor(this.color,.1):'transparent',
      color:'red'
 }
}
```

#### Inline css of element in Safari (after removing variable)

[image: Inline css of element in Safari (after removing variable)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your effort. I have tried splitting these properties and every property showed up in the browser except the color property. But finally I found out that somebody passed color "rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"  (so only rgb with alpha channel  ). In the end a missing letter 'a' was causing problem with css. Chrome was able somehow to reproduce it as rgba but other browsers weren't

Answer (score 0):

Depending on Safari and IE versions you are using, it is possible that shorthand `background` property is not supported.

While statically defined styles are processed during build time with [postcss](https://postcss.org/) or an alternative in your project, dynamically bound styles are not compiled for browser compatibility.

To resolve such issue, try splitting shorthand `background` property into relevant styles. In example above using only `background-color` should be enough:

```
return {
  backgroundColor: this.hoverx ? _color.getColor(this.color, 0.1) : 'transparent',
  // ... other styles
}
```

If you need to overwrite other background options, you can specify them individually:

```
backgroundImage: 'none',
backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
backgroundPosition: 'center center',
backgroundSize: 'cover'
```